# Can't download from AWS boto3 generated signed url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to upload a file to an existing AWS s3 bucket, generate a public URL and use that URL (somewhere else) to download the file.
I'm closely following the [example here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls):

```
import os
import boto3
import requests
import tempfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as outfile:
    outfile.write("dummycontent")
    file_name = outfile.name

with open(file_name, mode="r") as outfile:
    s3.upload_file(outfile.name, "twistimages", "filekey")

os.unlink(file_name)


url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'twistimages',
        'Key': 'filekey'
    }
)

response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

I would expect to see a success return code (200) from the requests library.

Instead, stdout is: <Response [400]>

Also, if I navigate to the corresponding URL with a webbrowser, I get an XML file with an error code: `InvalidRequest` and an error message:

> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please
>   use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

How can I use boto3 to generate a public URL, which can easily be downloaded by any user by just navigating to the corresponding URL, without generating complex headers?

Why does the example code from the official documentation not work in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. I'm using an S3 bucket in the `eu-central-1` region and after specifying the region in the config file, everything worked as expected and the script stdout was `<Response [200]>`.

The configuration file (`~/.aws/config`) now looks like:

```
[default]
region=eu-central-1
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS S3 still support legacy old v2 signature in US region(prior 2014). But under new AWS region, only AWS4-HMAC-SHA256(s3v4) are allowed.

To support this features , you must specify them explicitly in .aws/config file or during boto3.s3 resource/client instantiation.  e.g.

```
# add this entry under ~/.aws/config
[default]
s3.signature_version = s3v4

[other profile]
s3.signature_version = s3v4
```

Or declare them explicitly

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3', config= boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

s3resource = boto3.resource('s3', config= boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help to clarify how adding this option helps me to achieve the goal of creating a URL, which can be used to download the file using a Webbrowser or the default settings of the python `requests` library? I followed your instructions, however the code snippet I posted still returns an HTTP code 400, so it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: I can't downvote the answer. But please note that it did not help to solve the issue. I found the answer myself, see below.

Comment: @Kai  please use try: except: to print out the error. Or send the output using the logging module.